# VB.Net Windows8 SettingFlyout with WebView not navigating

Tags: vb.net, xaml, webview, windows-8, flyout

In the setting flyout XAML:

```
<SettingsFlyout
    x:Class="D_Day.CustomWebview"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:D_Day"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="CustomWebview"
    Padding="0"
    d:DesignWidth="346"
>
    <StackPanel Background="#ff121212" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <WebView x:Name="webView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />    
    </StackPanel>
</SettingsFlyout>
```

and in the .VB :

```
Private Sub CustomWebview_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    webView.Navigate(New Uri("http://google.com"))
End Sub
```

When the setting flyout shows, the webview never starts navigating.
Only a blank view(don't know whether it's a webpage or an empty thing) appears.

Is it impossible to implement WebView on the SettingFlyout?

Comment: You have to hook up the *Loaded* event in the xaml for the webview

Comment: @chuex CustomWebview_Loaded Sub is successfully called after the flyout load.

Answer (score 0):

With your specific xaml, you have to set the width and height on the WebView.  What you currently have causes the control to have a width/height of zero.

The following webview xaml works for me:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Width="320" Height="400"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```